# understanding insert, on conflict (upsert) in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand what the `set_` means in SQLAlchemy's `on_conflict_do_update` method.  i have the following Table:

```
Table(
    "test",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("firstname", String(100)),
    Column("lastname", String(100)),
)
```

and what insert some like this (if i wrote it in psql)

```
INSERT INTO test (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET firstname = EXCLUDED.firstname, lastname = EXCLUDED.lastname
```

I did some due diligence and saw people write in the `set_` like this:

```
import sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

insert_stmt = postgresql.insert(target).values([{'id':1,'firstname':'John','lastname':'Doe'}])
primary_keys = [key.name for key in inspect(target).primary_key]
update_dict = {c.name: c for c in insert_stmt.excluded if not c.primary_key}

stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements = primary_keys , set_ = update_dict)
engine.execute(stmt)
```

Is the `update_dict` just looking at the EXCLUDED values (the ones I want to update with) that I set in my `insert_stmt`?  If I `str(update_dict`) I get an dictionary of specific information regarding the column `{'firstname': Column('firstname', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<excluded>), 'lastname': Column('lastname', VARCHAR(length=100), table=<excluded>)}`, is the method above the only way to retrieve the data?  Can you write it out manually?